# Branch per feature\story\epic VS branch per sub-task in a Frontend+Backend repo?

Tags: git, mercurial, jira

We have a team in web development project and we've decided to go with a single repository with its pros and cons. We have our backlog split up into Jira stories and every story has several FE and BE tasks. Like:

1. ABC-1 Display cats

   1.1. ABC-2 [FE] Display cats markup

   1.2. ABC-3 [FE] Send CRUD requests for cats

   1.3. ABC-4 [BE] Create CRUD endpoints for cats

The question is should we create a single branch `abc-1-display-cats` and put FE+BE commits in it and then merge it into `dev` branch, **OR** should we create small `abc-2-display-cats-markup`, `abc-4-create-crud-endpoints-cats` branches for each sub-task and then merge every small branch into `dev` ?

Branch per feature

- +we can easily remove feature by `undo 1 merge commit`
- -anyone can break a feature branch with his code

Branch per subtask

- +everyone works in his own branch and may break codebase
- -we cannot simply remove a feature of 5-6 branches

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a feature branch like `abc-1-display-cats` branch from `dev` branch. For each of the subtask create a new branch `abc-4-create-crud-endpoints-cats` from the feature branch `abc-1-display-cats` and merge it back to the same feature branch. `dev` branch will interact only with feature branch, so you can perform rollback of whole feature. Also each developer can work independently on its subtask branch.